# How to form one to many relation for values in Excel sheets using Python script?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, python-2.7, loops

I have an Excel having few sheets as below given in attachment as well:

[image]

[image]

```
sheet 1 contains : 
SOURCE-KEY  PAYER-NAME  PAYER-CODE-TYPE PAYER-CODE
1           INDUSTRY    PAY             123485
2           LEADING     PAY             123422

Sheet 2 contains :
SOURCE-KEY  RECIEVER-KEY    RECIEVER-KEY-TYPE   RECIEVER-NAME   RECIEVER-CODE
1           1               PERSON              CEO             A222222221
1           2               PERSON              CO-FOUNDER      A222222221
2           3               PERSON              CFO             A222222221
```

Now I want to generate one to many algorithm between two sheets that means for every value of SOURCE_KEY print all values in RECEIVER SHEET

means :

```
INFORMATION SOURCE KEY 1: parent
    SERVICE PROVIDER  KEY 1: child
    SERVICE PROVIDER KEY  2: child 
INFORMATION SOURCE KEY 2: parent 
    SERVICE PROVIDER  KEY 3: child
    SERVICE PROVIDER KEY  4: child
```

Below is the code Written :

```
def loop_2100A(self,source_keys):   
    Information_Reciever = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=1, index_col=0)
    Reciever_keys=list(Information_Reciever["RECIEVER KEY"])
    Source_key_in_Reciever=list(Information_Reciever.index.values)
    elem =1
    elems_in_both_lists = set(Source_key_in_Reciever) & set(Reciever_keys

    if elem in elems_in_both_lists:
        print("Value of Source key inside if ", elem)
        print("Value of Reciever Key inside if", elem)
        res = dict(zip(Source_key_in_Reciever, Reciever_keys))

    for p in source_keys:
            print("Value of P is ",p)
       for x,y in res.items():
                print("COMPARING of p is {} and Value of x is {} IF EQUAL GO AHEAD ".format(p,x))
          if[p==x]:
                print("Value of Source key passed in 2100A is", x)
                print("Value of Reciever key passed to 2100B is", y)
               # CALLING SOME FUNCTION TO PERFORM OPERATION ONLY WHEN P==X
        else:
            print("Return back to Parent tag")
    return len(source_keys)

def run(self):
Read_Excel = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=0,index_col=0)
    source_keys = list(Read_Excel.index.values)
    segs = self.loop_2100A(Parser, filename,source_keys)
```

OUTPUT:

```
*********Inside 2100A loop*********
Value of Source key inside if  1
Value of Reciever Key inside if 1
Dictionary formed is {1: 2, 2: 3}
Value of P is  1
COMPARING of p is 1 and Value of x is 1 IF EQUAL GO AHEAD
Value of Parent Source key passed in 2100A is 1
Value of Child Reciever key passed to 2100B is 2
COMPARING of p is 1 and Value of x is 2 IF EQUAL GO AHEAD
****Value of Parent Source key passed in 2100A is 2
Value of Child Reciever key passed to 2100B is 3****
Value of P is  2
COMPARING of p is 2 and Value of x is 1 IF EQUAL GO AHEAD
**Value of Parent Source key passed in 2100A is 1
Value of Child Reciever key passed to 2100B is 2**
COMPARING of p is 2 and Value of x is 2 IF EQUAL GO AHEAD
Value of Parent Source key passed in 2100A is 2
Value of Child Reciever key passed to 2100B is 3

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Expected Output:

```
*********Inside 2100A loop*********
Value of Source key inside if  1
Value of Reciever Key inside if 1
Dictionary formed is {1: 2, 2: 3}
Value of P is  1
COMPARING of p is 1 and Value of x is 1 IF EQUAL GO AHEAD
Value of Parent Source key passed in 2100A is 1
Value of Child Reciever key passed to 2100B is 2
COMPARING of p is 1 and Value of x is 2 IF EQUAL GO AHEAD
NOT EQUAL Return back to Parent tag
Value of P is  2
COMPARING of p is 2 and Value of x is 1 IF EQUAL GO AHEAD
NOT EQUAL Return back to Parent tag
COMPARING of p is 2 and Value of x is 2 IF EQUAL GO AHEAD
Value of Parent Source key passed in 2100A is 2
Value of Child Reciever key passed to 2100B is 3

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Bold ones in output is coming wrong. So even if the comparison of P and X fails it is going inside If condition, or my be for loop and if conditions are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Use `if p == x:` instead of `if [p == x]:`. They are different.

```py
    if [2 == 3]:  # if [False]:
        print('passed');  # 'passed' will be printed
```

```py
    if 2 == 3:  # if False:
        print('passed');  # 'passed' will not be printed
```

The `[False]` object is considered `True`. You can check it by executing `print(bool([False]))`, which prints `True`.

You can see the documentation about [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) in Python.

Comment: can you please help me with this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62417455/aws-lambda-read-zip-file-perform-validation-and-unzip-to-s3-bucket-if-validation

Comment: @HarshitKakkar I posted an answer to the question:)