# AWS lambda read zip file perform validation and unzip to s3 bucket if validation is passed

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a requirement in which a zip files arrives on s3 bucket, I need to write a lambda using python to read the zip file perform some validation and unzip on another S3 bucket.

Zip file contains below:

```
a.csv b.csv c.csv trigger_file.txt
```

trigger_file.txt -- contain names of files in zip and record count (example: a.csv:120 , b.csv:10 , c.csv:50 )

So using lambda I need to read trigger file check if number files in zip folder is equal to number of files mentioned in trigger file if pass the unzip to s3 bucket.

Below code I have prepared :

```
def write_to_s3(config_dict):
    inp_bucket = config_dict["inp_bucket"]
    inp_key = config_dict["inp_key"]
    out_bucket = config_dict["out_bucket"]
    des_key = config_dict["des_key"]
    processed_key = config_dict["processed_key"]

    obj = S3_CLIENT.get_object(Bucket=inp_bucket, Key=inp_key)
    putObjects = []
    with io.BytesIO(obj["Body"].read()) as tf:
        # rewind the file
        tf.seek(0)

    # Read the file as a zipfile perform transformations and process the members
    with zipfile.ZipFile(tf, mode='r') as zipf:
        for file in zipf.infolist():
            fileName = file.filename
            print("file name before while loop :",fileName)
            try:
                found = False
                while not found :
                    if fileName == "Trigger_file.txt" :
                        with zipf.open(fileName , 'r') as thefile:
                            my_list = [i.decode('utf8').split(' ') for i in thefile]
                            my_list = str(my_list)[1:-1]
                            print("my_list :",my_list)
                            print("fileName :",fileName)
                            found = True
                            break
                            thefile.close()
                    else:
                        print("Trigger file not found ,try again")
            except Exception as exp_handler:
                    raise exp_handler

            if 'csv' in fileName :
                try:
                    if fileName in my_list:
                        print("Validation Success , all files in Trigger file  are present procced for extraction")
                    else:
                        print("Validation Failed")
                except Exception as exp_handler:
                    raise exp_handler

    # *****FUNCTION TO UNZIP ********


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        inp_bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
        inp_key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')
        config_dict = build_conf_obj(os.environ['config_bucket'],os.environ['config_file'], os.environ['param_name'])
        write_to_s3(config_dict)
    except Exception as exp_handler:
        print("ERROR")
```

All was going well, only issue I am facing is in validation part, I think while loop is wrong, since it is going into infinite loop.

Expectation:

Search for trigger_file.txt in zip folder if found then break the loop do validation and unzip it to s3 folder. If not found keep searching until end of dict.

ERROR OUTPUT ( timing out):

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "2020-06-16T20:09:06.168Z 39253b98-db87-4e65-b288-b585d268ac5f Task timed out after 60.06 seconds"
}

Request ID:
"39253b98-db87-4e65-b288-b585d268ac5f"

Function Logs:
 again
Trigger file not found ,try again
Trigger file not found ,try again
Trigger file not found ,try again
Trigger file not found ,try again
Trigger file not found ,trEND RequestId: 39253b98-db87-4e65-b288-b585d268ac5f
REPORT RequestId: 39253b98-db87-4e65-b288-b585d268ac5f  Duration: 60060.06 ms   Billed Duration: 60000 ms   Memory Size: 3008 MB    Max Memory Used: 83 MB  Init Duration: 389.65 ms    
2020-06-16T20:09:06.168Z 39253
```

Comment: What is it printing (if anything)? What happens when you increase the Lambda function's runtime from 60 seconds to 15m?

Comment: You could also look into using the builtin Python tempfile library to save the text file locally before attempting to read from it? You also shouldn't be using a while loop here. Unnecessary infinite loops just make debugging more difficult and crashes more likely.

Comment: Please correct the indentation of your code.

Comment: so there is no solution to read the zip file on fly and do validations ???

Comment: When I increase Lambda runtime from 60 sec to 15 min it goes into infinite loop printing " Trigger file not found , try again " many times and timing out after 15 mins

Answer (score 1):

In the following while loop in your code, if `fileName` is not `"Trigger_file.txt"`, it falls into infinite loop.

> ```
> found = False
> while not found:
>     if fileName == "Trigger_file.txt":
>         with zipf.open(fileName , 'r') as thefile:
>             my_list = [i.decode('utf8').split(' ') for i in thefile]
>             my_list = str(my_list)[1:-1]
>             print("my_list :",my_list)
>             print("fileName :",fileName)
>             found = True
>             break
>             thefile.close()
>     else:
>         print("Trigger file not found ,try again")
> ```

---

I think you can replace part of your `write_to_s3` function code by the following code:

```py
def write_to_s3(config_dict):

    ######################
    #### Do something ####
    ######################    

    # Read the file as a zipfile perform transformations and process the members
    with zipfile.ZipFile(tf, mode='r') as zipf:
        found = False
        for file in zipf.infolist():
            fileName = file.filename
            if fileName == "Trigger_file.txt":
                with zipf.open(fileName, 'r') as thefile:
                    my_list = [i.decode('utf8').split(' ') for i in thefile]
                    my_list = str(my_list)[1:-1]
                    print("my_list :", my_list)
                    print("fileName :", fileName)
                    found = True
                    thefile.close()
                    break

        if found is False:
            print("Trigger file not found ,try again")
            return

        for file in zipf.infolist():
            fileName = file.filename
            if 'csv' in fileName:
                if fileName not in my_list:
                    print("Validation Failed")
                    return

        print("Validation Success , all files in Trigger file  are present procced for extraction")

    # *****FUNCTION TO UNZIP ********
```

Comment: Thank you so much , I also used the exact same logic scrape out the older one.

Comment: Hello Gorisanson , could you please help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66964780/reshape-function-in-pyspark-transpose-a-column

Answer (score 0):

Read the zipped file into a buffer, extract all filenames using the zipfile library. Then, you can add an if statement in the for loop here: for `file in zipped.namelist():` (without the extension).

```
        zipped_file = s3_resource.Object(bucket_name=sourcebucketname, key=filekey)
        buffer = BytesIO(zipped_file.get()["Body"].read())
        zipped = zipfile.ZipFile(buffer)
        
        for file in zipped.namelist():
            logger.info(f'current file in zipfile: {file}')
            final_file_path = file + '.extension'

            with zipped.open(file, "r") as f_in:
                content = f_in.read()
                destinationbucket.upload_fileobj(io.BytesIO(content),
                                                        final_file_path,
                                                        ExtraArgs={"ContentType": "text/plain"}
                                                )
```

There's also a tutorial here: https://betterprogramming.pub/unzip-and-gzip-incoming-s3-files-with-aws-lambda-f7bccf0099c9