# Reshape function in Pyspark (transpose a column)

Tags: python, r, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on converting an R script to Pyspark, and got stuck on one point. Below is the code from R script :

```
## Transposing the stacked trt section to wider set for Outcome ID set
## c("Trial.ID", "Arm.ID", "Re.randomized.arm.id", "Phase.ID", "Period.ID")

TRT <- select(trt_stacked, -Planned.Treatment.ID) %>% 
  renameCol(c("Treatment.Administration.days.x", "Treatment.Administration.days.y"),
            c("Treatment.Administration.days.plan", "Treatment.Administration.days.act") )  %>% 
  reshape(direction = "wide", 
          idvar = c("Trial.ID", "Arm.ID", "Re.randomized.arm.id", "Phase.ID", "Period.ID",
                    "Phase", "Phase.Duration", "Phase.Duration.unit", "Phase.Description",
                    "Period", "Period.Duration", "Period.Dur.Unit", "Period.Description"), 
          timevar="Treatment.ID")
```

I need to convert this piece of code into Pyspark, although there is a pivot function in spark which does the transpose, but I am not aware of functionality of this "Reshape" function.

I know the output that this reshape function is transposing all column except in idvar to rows for all distinct value of treatment_id. It is also concatenating treatment_id to all the transpose columns like below:

```
Titration.1
Titration.Duration.1
Titration.Duration.Unit.1
Titration.Target.1
Titration.Value.1
Titration.unit.1
Treatment.name.1
Treatment.Class.1
Treatment.Description.1
Treatment.Start.Time.1
Treatment.End.Time.1

Titration.2
Titration.Duration.2
Titration.Duration.Unit.2
Titration.Target.2
Titration.Value.2
Titration.unit.2
Treatment.name.2
Treatment.Class.2
Treatment.Description.2
Treatment.Start.Time.2
Treatment.End.Time.2
```

Does reshape function in R drop nulls values as well? Is there a similar function in Spark or Python?

Input :

```
    |treatment_id|arm_id|re_randomized_arm_id|trial_id|phase_id| phase|phase_duration|phase_duration_unit|phase_description|titration|titration_duration|titration_duration_unit|titration_target|titration_value|titration_unit|
1|1|-999|16|1|Active|NA|NA|NA|titration|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA
2|1|-999|16|1|Active|NA|NA|NA|titration|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA
2|1|-999|16|1|Active|NA|NA|NA|No titration|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA
```

Expected output after transpose :

```
|treatment_id|arm_id|re_randomized_arm_id|trial_id|phase_id| phase|phase_duration|phase_duration_unit|phase_description|titration_1|titration_duration_1|titration_duration_unit_1|titration_target_1|titration_value_1|titration_unit_1|titration_2|titration_duration_2|titration_duration_unit_2|titration_target_2|titration_value_2|titration_unit_2|
1|1|-999|16|1|Active|NA|NA|NA|titration|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA
2|1|-999|16|1|Active|NA|NA|NA|titration|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|No titration|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA
```

What new things can I try to resolve this problem?

Comment: `reshape` can perform transformations from long to wide format and visa versa. It does **not** remove null values but will **insert** null values if transforming to wide format and there are missing values in the long format. 2 similar functions in python are the `pandas.DataFrame.wide_to_long` and `pandas.DataFrame.long_to_wide` functions. Several guides for achieveing this with spark exist out there (both on SO and not on SO) for example [here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/how-to-pivot-table-and-unpivot-a-spark-dataframe/).

Comment: Yes I checked this one but how will we have multiple columns appending id in column names ?

Comment: @Gorisanson could you please help here?

Comment: @HarshitKakkar I'm sorry about that maybe I couldn't help you for this problem. For now, I have almost no experience in R or in Apache Spark.

Comment: Can we do the same in python ,, transposing a row in multiple columns ...I just want to transpose distinct value of treatment_id into multiple columns

Comment: Helpful feedback for you Harshit. I have several times trimmed please-help-me pleading from your questions, as technical writing is generally preferred here. On this occasion I have downvoted, in order to help you remember. More information about this kind of edit [can be found in this post here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391945).

Comment: I don't know about Python, but in R spark via sparklyr you should be able to use the pivot_longer and pivot_wider functions to achieve basically the same thing as your reshape. sparklyr supports dplyr verbs, so your select and rename statements will work, too.